# Convert gaussian $XYZ$ into magnetic heading

Tags: geometric-construction

OK, so I'm stuck, I've tried a combination of what I can find in terms of atan, atan2.

I have a Yost Labs sensor. In the 3D Test Suite it's showing a heading of $\sim234$ magnetic degrees which seems about right. Going to terminal mode I get this raw data:

$$0.10613,-0.41741,-0.07403$$

Description of raw data:

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeMs3.png)

Sensor settings

[Settings for sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdwVS.png)

In no way have I been able to get that raw data to $\sim234$.

Looking for a formula to convert these gaussian vectors to magnetic heading.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is also a compass reference vector value the can be retrieved.

Compass reference vector 0.00000,-0.95839,0.28547